# iPhone : Countdown problems (00:00:00 format)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, countdown

I use a UISlider to get the input in minutes (range 1 - 120) for a countdown timer and show it on a label like this "01:30:00". 
i) I would like when the user sets the timer (using the slider) to adjust the hours and minutes but NOT the seconds. The seconds should start counting AFTER the user starts the countdown. How can i do that?
ii) i have trouble updating the countdownlabel. Could somebody suggest the correct code?

```
-(IBAction)setTime:(id)sender {
totaltime=timeSlider.value;
hours = totaltime / 60;
minutes = (totaltime % 3600) % 60;
seconds = (totaltime % 3600) * 60;
[countDownLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DBLCDTempBlack" size:45]];
countDownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2i:%.2i:%.2i", hours, minutes, seconds]; }

 -(void)countdown {
 totaltime -=1; 


if(minutes == 0) { [timer invalidate]; }    
 [countDownLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DBLCDTempBlack" size:45]];
 countDownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2i:%.2i:%.2i", hours, minutes, seconds]; }
-(IBAction)fade {
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                        target:self selector:@selector (countdown)  userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)setTime:(id)sender {
totaltime=timeSlider.value;
hours = totaltime / 60;
minutes = (totaltime % 3600) % 60;
seconds = (totaltime % 3600) * 60;
[countDownLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DBLCDTempBlack" size:45]];
countDownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2i:%.2i:%.2i", hours, minutes, seconds]; }

 -(void)countdown {
 totaltime -=1; 
totaltime=timeSlider.value;
hours = totaltime / 60;
minutes = (totaltime % 3600) % 60;
seconds = (totaltime % 3600) * 60;
countDownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2i:%.2i:%.2i", hours, minutes, seconds];


if(minutes == 0) { [timer invalidate]; }    
 [countDownLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"DBLCDTempBlack" size:45]];
 countDownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2i:%.2i:%.2i", hours, minutes, seconds]; }
-(IBAction)fade {
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                        target:self selector:@selector (countdown)  userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; }
```

Comment: That still doesn't update the countdownlabel. Also the way i set the seconds is wrong. It show 4 figure number.

Comment: Ok, after erasing the "totaltime=timeSlider.value;" under the -(void) the countdown started however without knowing how to calculate seconds, i can not properly invalidate my timer. PLEASE HELP!!!!

Comment: Ok, i figured how to calculate hours, min, sec. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You're decrementing `totalTime` but not re-calculating your hours, minutes and seconds. So I imagine when you start the countdown, nothing ever changes? You need to recalculate the hours, minutes and seconds within your `countdown` method.

Comment: Shouldn't the hours, min, sec be recalculated every time i decrease totaltime by one (totaltime-=1;) ???

Comment: Basically "totaltime=timeSlider.value;" resets the countdown counting but i don't know how to avoid it...

Comment: Regarding your first comment, yes, that is my point. For your second, don't call that code. You only set total time from the slider when you initially set up the alarm.